# Can I POST data in PHP and then use the Header command?

Tags: php, jquery, post

```
$bEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bEmail']);
$bPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bPassword']);
/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Do/LogonForm
header("Location: /cart/payment");
```

I want to POST the form `/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Do/LogonForm` in jQuery you can do:

```
$.post('/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Do/LogonForm', {
email: <?=$bEmail?>,
password: <?=$bPassword?>
},
window.location="cart/payment"
```

I want to do this in PHP, so PHP runs a script, this page sends a `POST` back and whilst the script is running at the end it uses the `Header` to redirect.

Comment: I edited your code, you want some alternative to `$.post` jQuery in PHP, example `.POSTcmd`

Comment: To which output do want to post the form if the output gets redirected afterwards? There is a logical error in your problem definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can ....

```
$bEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bEmail']);
$bPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bPassword']);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com//webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Do/LogonForm';
$fields = array(                
            'bEmail'=>urlencode($bEmail),
            'bPassword'=>urlencode($bPassword)
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

and then redirect

```
header("Location: /cart/payment");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `header` function whenever you would like as long as no output has been sent to the browser (i.e no HTML source or `echo`'s can come before the `header` call).